# My Javascript isn't working in Joomla 3, is something conflicting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0

I have very siple javascript working in jsFiddle but for some reason when I add to Joomla 3 CMS it doesn't work. The content stays static and does not move. I am putting the html and js in a HTML Module with no WYSIWYG editor and even tried putting the js in external file and no dice. Any thoughts?

```
function ticker() {
    $('#jsTicker li:first').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).appendTo($('#jsTicker')).slideDown(1500);
    });
}
setInterval(ticker, 6000);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/Zh3wU/
site: http://bit.ly/13GerYd

Comment: Have you tried using firebug? The console will tell you if there's an error, and right now it's telling you that $(...) is not defined, so you're probably using mootools side to side with jQuery and that's causing your problem. Try Vipul Sharma's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `<script type="javascript">` instead of `<script type="application/javascript">`

**EDIT**

You've also forgot an extra }); in the end.

Comment: You just need to add an extra `});` before `</script>. Your parentheses don't match.

Comment: Sorry, before the `setInterval`. there was nothing wrong with the `setInterval` you had

Comment: You've also loaded jQuery with noConflict(). You need to change your `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: In most browsers, when you press F12, a console will open, showing what errors happens during loading. Right now the error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: ticker is not defined`. And indeed there is no such function in your code.

Comment: It probably was what you had in the beginning, minus the typos I've mentioned in the main answer.

Comment: haha yea, finally got it: http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/Zh3wU/. Do you know how I can change the effect to fadeIn/fadeout instead of slidedown? Just changing .slideDown to .fadeIn is no good

Comment: Also do I have to close the loop somehow? After a while it crashes whatever browser is running

Comment: needs something more than fadeOut or fadeIn, is still slides

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery no conflict as :

```
var jat =  $.noConflict();
```

now replace $ in your code with jat

Answer (score 0):

Running the provided code in a console on the example page shows it working, so I think you have a document ready issue.

You should run the function in a jQuery document ready statement. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: this didn't help, see site